# Unable to upgrade Neo4j store from 3.2.2 to 3.5.1

Tags: neo4j

I'm attempting to upgrade a Neo4j community 3.2.2 store to 3.5.1 but none of the node or relationship data is showing up.

I have Neo4j Community 3.2.2 running on an older laptop that I've had to maintain because of legacy issues, but now I want to migrate to 3.5.1.  I changed the config file to allow for updates (dbms.allow_upgrade=true) and changed the name of the store to graph.db.  Neo4j loads correctly and the log file says the upgrade happened.  However, all of the node and relationship information isn't showing up in the browser.  sysinfo shows that the total store size is the same but all of the other information is missing.

Is the difference in versions too great to make the upgrade or am I just missing something?

=Edit=

Looking deeper in the log file, I see the lines:

> 2019-02-01 16:17:28.698+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Requirement `Database available` makes database graph.db unavailable.
>
> 2019-02-01 16:17:28.699+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is unavailable.

And later:

> 2019-02-01 16:17:31.735+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.i.l.NativeLabelScanStore] No label index found, this might just be first use. Preparing to rebuild.

Is something getting lost forcing a rebuild?

Comment: Do you have any plugins? If so did you simply copy the plugins over, or did you check if there were updated plugins for 3.5 you should use instead?

Comment: I haven't installed any plugins in either version.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to upgrade from 3.2 to 3.5.
Have you followed this doucmentation (it seems so) : https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.5/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/

If you have a problem, generally it comes from the copy of the database. You should be sure to have a clean shutdown of Neo4j before to make the copy.

Comment: Yes, that's what I followed and I always shut down Neo4j before saving or transferring the backups.  I added some lines from the log file to the original comment but I couldn't find much online about this specific message.